# How to solve $x=\arctan(\tan(-8))$?

Tags: trigonometry

How to solve $x=\arctan(\tan(-8))$?

My instinct would just be to say $x=-8$ but I think that there is some restrictions with domains of $\tan(x)$ any help?

Comment: Did you try to compute this on your calculator?

Comment: The arctangent is constrained to be between $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$, so you want to find an angle in that range that has the same tangent as $-8$ has. For that, use the periodicity of the tangent function.

Comment: Yes it gave something like $1.4.....$

Comment: @Tpm It will have given you $3\pi - 8$.

Comment: $3\pi-8$ is the searcehd result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your instincts are correct. $\arctan$ will yield values in $[-\frac\pi2, \frac\pi2]$, so you must reduce $-8 \bmod \pi$ (because $\tan$ is $\pi$-periodic) into said range. This will give
$$x = 3\pi - 8 = 1.424777960769379715387\ldots$$
(You can also ask [W|A](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arctan%28tan%28-8%29%29&a=TrigRD_R))

Comment: How do you get that $tan(x)=tan(3\pi-x)$?

Comment: @Tpm $\tan$ is $\pi$-periodic, i.e. $\tan(x+\pi) = \tan(x) = \tan(x+k\pi)$ for any $k\in\mathbb Z$. You equation is false, instead, $\tan(-8) = \tan(-8 + 3\pi) = \tan(3\pi - 8)$ and $3\pi-8\in[-\frac\pi2, \frac\pi2]$ so $\arctan(\tan(-8)) = \arctan(\tan(3\pi-8)) = 3\pi -8$.

Comment: Beautiful explanation. Many thanks.

Comment: You can use $((x+\pi/2)\bmod\pi)-\pi/2$.

Answer (score 2):

Use the fact that $\tan x$ is $\pi$-periodic and that the range of $\arctan x$ is $[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$.